# Stop the inversion of Y axis in camera

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, matrix, openframeworks

I have a program in which I have a simple rectangle drawn over the screen. When I put the rectangle inside a camera such as a `ofEasyCam`, it translates the position of the rectangle to the centre of the screen. Also, it flips the figure vertically and gives me an inverted drawing of the rectangle.

I have lots of objects on the screen and all of them appear inverted. How do I prevent the camera from rotating the Y-axis so that my object appears as is?

Comment: People will need more information to help you.  This could be caused by any number of things.  What are vertex positions of your rectangle?  Any UV coordinates?  What is your projection matrix?  Any other transformations applied to your rectangle?

Comment: Just noticed the "openframeworks" tag.  You should really put details of what tools you're using in the title and body of your question.  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [link](http://dev.openframeworks.cc/pipermail/of-dev-openframeworks.cc/2011-May/003207.html) which suggests there might be a bug, the solution suggested is to do the following:

```
cam.setScale(1, -1, 1);
```

It also mentioned that this occurred when they tried an "ofEasyCam - inside an ofFbo"